# Assistance with bash code to extract data line by line

Tags: bash, loops

I've been struggling with a new bash script I'm attempting to write.

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
/home/user1/public_html/pathtofile1
/home/user2/public_html/pathtofile2
/home/user3/public_html/packtofile3
```

I need code to read the text file line by line, extract the username so i can suspend it and put the full path (/home/user1/public_html/pathtofile1) as the reason its getting suspended.

Example of what i need it do automatically do:

```
/scripts/suspendacct user1 '/home/user1/public_html/pathtofile1' 1
/scripts/suspendacct user2 '/home/user1/public_html/pathtofile2' 1
/scripts/suspendacct user3 '/home/user1/public_html/pathtofile3' 1
```

I've tried a "for loop" and "while read line" and I'm having zero luck.

Also it needs to exclude duplicate usernames.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your attempts. The `while` version should work and is the correct approach. See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for discussion and examples.

Comment: Small typo, but should `/home/user3/public_html/packtofile3` in your first code block be `/home/user3/public_html/pathtofile3`?

Comment: Here is an example of the while version i have. Please note this is the first time using while read in my scripts

while read input
do
awk -F '/' '{print$3}' | sort -u
done < $textfile

This gives me the output of the usernames.

Comment: When you say `'/home/user1/public_html/pathtofile1'` -- many of the answers here have interpreted that as meaning you want _literal_ quotes, so, if you were writing this on a command line, what they gave you would be equivalent to `"'/home/user1/public_html/pathtofile1'"`. Is that genuinely what you want, or has your intent been misinterpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop approach was fine, you probably just ran into trouble parsing the `line`. You can use either **parameter expansion/substring extraction** or **substring replacement** to parse the needed information from the line. Below is an example of **parameter expansion/substring extraction**:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    usr="${line#/*/}"
    usr="${usr%%/*}"
    # /scripts/suspendacct $usr "'$line'"                   # uncomment for use
    printf "/scripts/suspendacct %s '%s'\n" $usr "$line"    # delete for use
done

exit 0
```

**Temporary Output**

```
$ bash suspendusr.sh <dat/usrpathtofile.txt
/scripts/suspendacct user1 '/home/user1/public_html/pathtofile1'
/scripts/suspendacct user2 '/home/user2/public_html/pathtofile2'
/scripts/suspendacct user3 '/home/user3/public_html/packtofile3'
```

**Note:** I simply have it printing what the `/scripts/suspendacct` call would be for each user. You will have to adjust the script and uncomment the actual call.

As you have figured out, there are probably a half-dozen ways to do this. All perfectly fine. Choose the approach you are comfortable with.

---

### skip duplicates

```
declare -a uarray
declare -i found=0

while read -r line; do
    usr="${line#/*/}"
    usr="${usr%%/*}"
    found=0
    for i in "${uarray[@]}"; do
        [ "$usr" = "$i" ] && found=1;
    done
    [ $found -eq 1 ] && continue
    uarray+=( $usr )
    # /scripts/suspendacct $usr "'$line'"                 # uncomment for use
    printf "/scripts/suspendacct %s '%s'\n" $usr "$line"  # delete for use
done
```

Using an individual check on each user is probably better than using the name as a regex. This will prevent any lesser included matches. (e.g. `user11` and `user111`)

Comment: Thank David, your way is working the best so far. I forgot to mention In my original post i need to exclude duplicate usernames.

Comment: Ok, I'll add a check for duplicates.

Comment: Is splitting `usr` intentional? I don't see a clear specification from the user either way, but perhaps I'm just missing it.

Comment: While I'm being pedantic, `${uarray[@]}` should be `"${uarray[@]}"`; otherwise, you might as well have used `${uarray[*]}`.

Comment: You of course are correct, but since it was Linux system user names that have no possibility of containing spaces, etc. I didn't quote, but I will fix :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `while` loop in bash:

```
# already processed users
declare -A seen

while read -r line; do
   IFS=/ read -ra arr <<< "$line"
   u="${arr[2]}"
   [[ ! "${seen[$u]}" ]] && seen["$u"]=1 && /scripts/suspendacct "${arr[2]}" "$line"
done < file
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot and report back.

Comment: This is working good, but i need to exclude duplicate usernames if possible.

Comment: Hmm check my updated answer for that unique processing.

Comment: Yes thank you, when it attempts to suspend the username, it says invalid user.

When i change /scripts/suspendacct "${arr[2]} '$line'" to echo "${arr[2]} '$line'" , it outputs in the correct format. I'm trying to see if i can fix it on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command, which uses a **single pipeline** and **avoids looping in the shell** altogether:

```
sort -t/ -k3,3 -u file | 
  awk -F/ '{ print $3 "\t" $0 }' | 
    xargs -n 2 -J {} echo /scripts/suspendacct {} 1
```

<sup>Remove `echo` above to actually run `suspendacct`.</sup>

- `sort -t/ -k3,3 -u file` sorts the input file by username (3rd field (`-k3,3`), based on separator `/` (`-t/`)) and eliminates duplicate usernames (`-u`).
- `awk -F/ '{ print $3 "\t" $0 }'` prepends the username to each input line:

  - `$3` is the 3rd field, based on separator `/` (`-F/`).
  - `$0` is the whole input line.
- `xargs -n 2 -J {} /scripts/suspendacct {} 1`
  invokes `/scripts/suspendacct` for every *pair* (`-n 2`) of whitespace-separated tokens in the input, i.e. for every username-path pair.

  - Note that the assumption is that both the username and the path do not have embedded whitespace (a safe assumption for the username) - if they did, that could be addressed as well; it is not addressed here for the sake of brevity.
  - `-J {}` simply defines placeholder `{}` for where the arguments will go.